# MySql import CSV space problem

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a data file which looks like that:

```
001,000,D,Bla bla bla
```

I import it into a mysql database with following code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
  INFILE 'D:\test.dat'
  INTO TABLE typen
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I get warnings for every line:

```
Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'typ1' at row 1
```

and when I look at the content of the table there is a space between every character. It looks like that:

```
 0 0 1 | 0 0 0 | D | B l a  b l a  b l a
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the file 8-bit, or some ghastly Unicode format?

Comment: do the type of each csv content match appropriate field type of the mysql table ?

Comment: I don't know the format of the file, but maybe there is the problem. The fields in the table have the size of 3,3,1,256 but the csv content does not fit in there because of the extra spaces.

Comment: I had a similar issue -- but my csv file was saved from excel in windows and loaded into mysql in linux vm -- issue was the line endings -- opened in text editor and set to linux line endings to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the encoding of the file. I did not find the correct encoding for this file so I opened it in Notepad++ changed the encoding to utf8 and used follwing code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
  INFILE 'D:\test.dat'
  INTO TABLE typen
  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```